# How does XCHG work in Intel assembly language?

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, instruction-set

How does the `xchg` instruction work in the following code? It is given that *arrayD* is a DWORD array of 1,2,3.

```
mov  eax, arrayD      ; eax=1
xchg eax, [arrayD+4]  ; eax=2 arrayD=2,1,3
```

Why isn't the array 1,1,3 after the `xchg`?

Comment: Why do you think the array has the values 2,1,3 at the end?

Comment: `mov eax, arrayD` does NOT set `eax` to `1`. It loads the address of `arrayD`. What you want is `mov eax, [arrayD]`.  Edit:misread the initial state.

Comment: @Jester That depends on the assembler. Some assemblers treat `arrayD` and `[arrayD]` the same.

Comment: @interjay yeah right. OP should have specified assembler.

Comment: So what is the correct code to change arrayD from 1,2,3 to 3,1,2?

Comment: Is that NASM syntax, or GAS `.intel_syntax`?  If it's GAS, then `mov eax, arrayD`  is in fact a load, but `;` is not the comment character!  Is it maybe MASM syntax?  I think `[arrayD+4]` might be legal MASM syntax, even though many people write `arrayD[4]` or `arrayD+4` with symbols outside square brackets in MASM.

Comment: `1,2,3` to `3,1,2` is more than one swap.

Comment: @AlloysiusGoh: I wouldn't use `xchg` at all; it's slow with a memory operand because it does an atomic exchange (implicit `lock` prefix.  See also http://agner.org/optimize/).  For `1,2,3` -> `3,1,2`, I'd load all 3 values into eax,ecx, and edx, then store them back.  Or do a 64-bit load of the first 2.  e.g. `mov rax, qword ptr [arrayD]` / `mov edx, [arrayD+8]` / `mov [arrayD], edx` / `mov qword ptr [arrayD+4], rax`.  Assuming you're using x86-64.  If you're on 32-bit, you can use `movq` into XMM0.

Comment: @PeterCordes It is intel syntax
My lecturer was just giving an example of how xchg works

Comment: Or I'd use `movdqu xmm0, [arrayD]` / `pshufd xmm0,xmm0, _MM_SHUFFLE(4,2,1,3)` / `movdqu [arrayD], xmm0`.  Use `vpmaskmovd` or AVX512 masked load/store if you need to avoid load/store of the dword past the end of the array.

Comment: @AlloysiusGoh: there are at least 3 flavours of Intel syntax used by different assemblers, see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/intel-syntax/info.  If the first instruction is supposed to be a load, then presumably it's MASM.

Comment: @PeterCordes From the way my lecturer seemed to explain it, it is safe to assume it's MASM

Comment: I always suggest to use squared brackets even in MASM to make the memory access easily visible upon reading the source, and to be consistent with non-symbol memory references, like `mov eax,[ebx]`. The MASM will ignore the `[]` around symbol names, so you can write `mov eax,[arrayD]` in such case. ... (and about +4 .. are you aware the memory is addressable by single bytes, so 32 bit value occupies 4 bytes in memory = the first element of that array occupies addresses `arrayD+0`, `arrayD+1`, `arrayD+2` and `arrayD+3`. The second element starts at address `arrayD+4` (and occupies mem up to +7)

Comment: In my earlier comment, shuffle indices are 0-indexed, so actually `_MM_SHUFFLE(3,1,0,2)`

Answer (score 13):

`xchg` works [like Intel's documentation says](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/XCHG.html).

I think the comment on the 2nd line is wrong.  **It should be `eax=2`, `arrayD = 1,1,3`.**  So you're correct, and you should email your instructor to say you think you've found a mistake, unless you missed something in your notes.

`xchg` only stores one element, and it can't magically look back in time to know where the value in eax came from and swap two memory locations with one `xchg` instruction.

The only way to swap `1,2` to `2,1` in one instruction would be a 64-bit rotate, like `rol qword ptr [arrayD], 32` (x86-64 only).

---

**BTW, don't use `xchg` with a memory operand if you care about performance.  It has an implicit `lock` prefix on 386 and later, so it's a full memory barrier, and even apart from waiting for the store buffer to drain, it takes about 20 CPU cycles on Haswell/Skylake (http://agner.org/optimize/ and https://uops.info/)**.  Of course, multiple instructions can be in flight at once, but `xchg mem,reg` is 8 uops, vs. 2 total for separate load + store.  `xchg` doesn't stall the pipeline, but the memory barrier hurts a lot (stopping later loads from being started early as well as waiting for earlier loads and stores to fully complete).  It's also a lot of work for the CPU to do to make it atomic.

Related:

- *[swapping 2 registers in 8086 assembly language(16 bits)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26469196/swapping-2-registers-in-8086-assembly-language16-bits)*  (how to efficiently swap a register with memory).  `xchg` is only useful for this case if you need atomicity, or if you care about code-size but not speed.  Or on CPUs before 386, where `xchg` doesn't imply `lock`.
- *[Can num++ be atomic for 'int num'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39393850/can-num-be-atomic-for-int-num)*
- *[Why is XCHG reg, reg a 3 micro-op instruction on modern Intel architectures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45766444/why-is-xchg-reg-reg-a-3-micro-op-instruction-on-modern-intel-architectures)* (for `xchg reg,reg`, no memory barrier)
- *[Are loads and stores the only instructions that gets reordered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50494658/are-loads-and-stores-the-only-instructions-that-gets-reordered/50496379#50496379)* - Instruction-level parallelism around `mfence` vs. a `lock`ed operation