# 8086 lock pin and ASM LOCK prefix how it works

Tags: assembly, locking, atomic, cpu-architecture, x86-16

I am a programmer and learning assembly language in order to intuitively understand how my code run on the CPU.

While I was studying the ASM keyword **LOCK**, google told me **CPU will take exclusive ownership of data bus while executing the following instruction with LOCK prefix.**

But without any extra information how CPU can **take exclusive ownership**.

I also found that 8086 microchip has a lock pin which do exactly the same thing as keyword **LOCK** does. This maybe the logic circuit which implements the **LOCK** keyword.

Can anyone explain the mechanism of the **lock pin**. While the lock pin is active, how other CPUs will be rejected when try to acquire the usage of data bus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the only CPU has the memory bus locked, no other device can read or change memory contents during that time, not even via DMA.  (Or with multiple CPUs on a shared bus with no cache, same deal.)  Therefore, no other memory operations at all can happen between the load and the store of a `lock add [di], ax` for example, making it atomic wrt. any possible observer.  (Other than a logic analyzer connected to the bus, which doesn't count.)

Semi-related: [Can num++ be atomic for 'int num'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39393850) describes how the `lock` prefix works on modern CPUs for cacheable memory, providing RMW atomicity *without* a bus lock, just hanging on to the cache line for the duration.

We call this a "cache lock"; all modern CPUs work this way for aligned `locked` operations, only doing an expensive bus lock on something like `xchg [mem], ax` that spans a boundary between two cache-lines.  That hurts throughput on all cores, and is so expensive that modern CPUs have a way to make that always fault, but not other unaligned loads/stores, as well as performance counters for it.

Fun fact: `xchg [mem], reg` has implicit `lock` semantics *on 386 and newer*.  (Which is unfortunate because it makes it unusable for performance reasons as just a plain load/store when you're running low on registers).  It didn't on 286 or earlier, unless you did `lock xchg`.  This is possibly related to the fact that there were SMP 386 systems (with a primitive sequentially-consistent memory model).  The modern x86 memory model applies to 486 and later SMP systems.

Comment: Semi-related for some `lock` prefix and `xchg` history: [How to exchange top of stack with register without implicit lock on latest 64 bit Intel CPUs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55880117)